# LUA - attempt to index global 'jit' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I am running ubuntu 16.04 on my machine.
And trying to run the following provided code, which always returns "attempt to index global 'jit' (a nil value)":

```
#!/usr/bin/env th

require 'torch'
require 'optim'

require 'paths'

require 'xlua'
require 'csvigo'

require 'nn'
require 'dpnn'

local opts = paths.dofile('opts.lua')

opt = opts.parse(arg)
print(opt)

torch.setdefaulttensortype('torch.FloatTensor')

if opt.cuda then
   require 'cutorch'
   require 'cunn'
   cutorch.setDevice(opt.device)
end

opt.manualSeed = 2
torch.manualSeed(opt.manualSeed)

paths.dofile('dataset.lua')
paths.dofile('batch-represent.lua')

model = torch.load(opt.model)
model:evaluate()
if opt.cuda then
   model:cuda()
end

repsCSV = csvigo.File(paths.concat(opt.outDir, "reps.csv"), 'w')
labelsCSV = csvigo.File(paths.concat(opt.outDir, "labels.csv"), 'w')

batchRepresent()

repsCSV:close()
labelsCSV:close()
```

I don't really understand why I am getting this error and how I can fix it.
What am I doing wrong?

full output

```
/home/yalishanda/torch/install/bin/lua: /home/yalishanda/openface/batch-represent/dataset.lua:130: attempt to index global 'jit' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    /home/yalishanda/openface/batch-represent/dataset.lua:130: in function '__init'
    /home/yalishanda/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/torch/init.lua:91: in function </home/yalishanda/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/torch/init.lua:87>
    [C]: in function 'dataLoader'
    .../yalishanda/openface/batch-represent/batch-represent.lua:19: in function 'batchRepresent'
    ../batch-represent/main.lua:42: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...anda/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myScript.py", line 47, in <module>
    ret, frameRGB = video_capture.read()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be running a normal Lua interpreter, but you need to be running LuaJIT (it provides the `jit` table that the modules used in the script expect to access). Since you are using Torch, make sure you use LuaJIT interpreter that is included with Torch and the issue should go away.

Comment: I tried sudo apt install libluajit-5.1-dev, but the error is still there. How should I proceed to use LuaJit which is included with Torch? I am just following those steps: http://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/demo-3-classifier/

Comment: Your torch installation is configured to run Lua (`/home/yalishanda/torch/install/bin/lua`), but you need to configure it to run LuaJIT. The instructions depend on how you installed/compiled Torch. See if the information in [this ticket](https://github.com/torch/torch7/issues/945) is of any help.

Comment: I m kind of confused. I installed everything from source as shown here: https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/setup/ . What do you think might be the correct approach?

Comment: The instructions on that page suggest to following instructions on torch.ch website. Did you follow http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html? Did you run `TORCH_LUA_VERSION=LUA52 ./install.sh` or did you run `./install.sh` instead? If you ran the latter you should get LuaJIT, but if you specified `TORCH_LUA_VERSION=LUA52` or `TORCH_LUA_VERSION=LUA51` you got the "normal" Lua interpreter.